# JPA auto increment for compound key

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

Lets say I want to model an issue tracker, and my model, consists of two entities: Repository and Issue. A repository may contain several issues. So you get approximately the following JPA classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="repository")
public class Repository {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue 
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

And for the Issue class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="issue")
@IdClass(Issue.IssuePk)
public class Issue {

   static class IssuePk implements Serializable {

        private Repository repository;
        private Integer issueNumber;
        // Getters, setters, equals and hashcode

    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Repository repository;

    @Id
    private Integer issueNumber;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Now I want the issue numbers to be generated in an auto increment-like way, but then local to the repository. I see various options, but I'm not sure whats best.

## Calculate Id manually when instantiating the issue

Not using any automatic generation, just setting the value before persisting. So: query the issues for the repository, calculate the maximum issue number (if any), increment, set and persist. This feels a bit error prone, because if you will instantiate issues from other segments of the code, you will need to keep this in mind.

```
Issue issue = new Issue();
issue.setRepository(repository);
// For example, assuming this is right for the context now:
issue.setIssueNumber(repository.getIssues().size() + 1);
```

(Obviously this one can being refactored to deduplicate this issue number generation but that does not prevent Issues with a `null` issueNumber being `persisted` on an `EntityManger`)

## JPA Lifecycle Events

Using JPA Lifecycle Events, hooking on the `@PrePersist` and doing the same there. This has the benefit that this is called automatically, and not has do be duplicated over the code base.

```
// On the issue entity
@PrePersist
void setIssueNumberOnPersist() {
     if(getIssueNumber() == null) {
          setIssueNumber(getRepository().getIssues().size() + 1);
      }
}
```

However it seems to conflict with one of the JPA restrictions:

> To avoid conflicts with the original database operation that fires the entity lifecycle event (which is still in progress) callback methods should not call EntityMan­ager or Query methods and should not access any other entity objects.

## Using Database triggers

Set the issueId value through a trigger on the issue table, and let JPA update it's value after insertion. A downsite of this approach is that this trigger has to be patched if switching databases.

I'm not really into writing triggers now, but I think it would roughly be:

```
before insert on issue
    select max(issue_id) as val from issue where repository = issue.repository
    issue_id = val + 1
end
```

Or using a cached value:

```
before insert on issue
    select next_issue_id as val from repository where id = issue.repository_id
    issue_id = val
    update repository set next_issue_id = val + 1 where id = issue.repository_id
end
```

## Using Hibernate `IdentifierGenerator`

It seems that a `IdentifierGenerator` would also be possible to do this job. However, it requires to interact with the DB through queries, and I think that this would break compatibility with different databases and schema changes.

```
 public class IssueIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

     public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
             throws HibernateException {

         Connection connection = session.connection();
         try {

             PreparedStatement ps = connection
                     .prepareStatement("... query ...");
             // Calculate the next issueId
             return issueId;
         } catch (SQLException e) {
             log.error(e);
             throw new HibernateException(
                     "Unable to generate Stock Code Sequence");
         }
         return null;
     }
 }
```

## An option that I am missing

If I'm missing an option, I'd be glad to hear!

What is the best option?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to cache the number of issues attached to a repository.

Therefore you create a field `issueCount` which would be initialized in the constructor by fetching from the database the amount and then incremented accordingly whenever an issue is created.

Keep in mind this must be synchronized, as you don't want to end up having 2 issues with the same id.

According to various stackoverflow questions and forum posts, this seems to be a known issue and Hibernate advises developers to create the logic in their project rather than depending on the `@GeneratedValue` of Hibernate.